# Not having EDA tool options in Quartus 16.1

Tags: ubuntu, vhdl, fpga, modelsim, quartus

I've installed Quartus 16.1 II prime on Ubuntu machine. But I do not have EDA tool options section in "Tools >> Options".

And according to [this](https://mil.ufl.edu/3701/docs/quartus/quartus15.0_Linux_installation_instructions.pdf) tutorial, I've installed this packages:

```
sudo apt install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libxft2:i386 libxext6:i386
```

And also `./vsim -help` command works well.

But as you see, I haven't **EDA tool options** in menus.
[image: Option section]

And also I can't run modelsim simulation for my projects:
[image: Simulation]

My OS is Ubuntu 17.04 .

---

**Update:** I've installed and troubleshot `Modelsim` with this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Altera_Design_Software#ModelSim-Altera_Edition) from arch wiki. And now I can run `Modelsim_GUI` with `vsim` command well. But also the problem remains and **EDA tool options** not shown in menus.

[image: Modelsim_GUI]

---

**Second update:** And when I run *Quartus* from command line, I do not receive any messages.

[image: Quartus_from_commandline]

Comment: using modelsim in ubuntu is really difficult in my experience. Modelsim needs many libraries to be compiled in 32 bit mode and such. Read [this](http://vineeshvs.blogspot.nl/2014/02/installing-and-using-modelsim-in-ubuntu.html) and [this](http://mattaw.blogspot.nl/2014/05/making-modelsim-altera-starter-edition.html). Don't expect support from mentor or altera, as they suck at doing so.

Comment: @JHBonarius Thnaks for your reply; But my problem is not about `modelsim`, I can run it well from command line with `vsim` command. My probelm is about Quartus thats as you see not shows the EDA tool options in menus.

Comment: Start Quartus from a terminal : any interesting/unusual/alarming messages in the terminal? Like missing libraries etc?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks dear Brian ; but nothing is appeared in terminal.